# keyboard mapping doesn't work anymore

Tags: keyboard, arch-linux

*[EDIT:  After the night it came back to normal. IMO it's a hardware pb because sometimes it comes back, and then disappear...]*

I don't know why, but suddently, the keys "a" and "q" begun to do the same action as the Screenshot key...

I went on my windows dual boot (I'm running archlinux): it's the same. I tried with `xev` and it appeared that those 2 letters are giving the same keycode (107).

**Must it be an hardware problem ? Can it be something else?**

(it seems that the combo FN+Left doesn't work anymore eather....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the EDIT,

After the night it came back to normal. IMO it's a hardware pb because sometimes it comes back, and then disappear. Maybe is it linked to the humidity of the room...

Answer (score 0):

Doe sound like a hardware issue. Lord knows keyboards die. Get a used one with a usb plug for 2 buX
at goodwill and see. Incidentally if its a laptop and you gotta switch or even clean it be VERY careful when you take the old out especially at the electrical ribbon connection. VERY. But dont fret theyre cheap enough to order a replacement part if needed. And when you snap a new one in youll know how. Depends on your model but beeeee careful it'll save you grief. I'm sure there are videos on you tube.